# PyCharm can't find 'SPARK_HOME' when imported from a different file

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark

I've two files.

> test.py

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark import SQLContext


class Connection():
    conf = SparkConf()
    conf.setMaster("local")
    conf.setAppName("Remote_Spark_Program - Leschi Plans")
    conf.set('spark.executor.instances', 1)
    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
    sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
    print ('all done.')

con = Connection()
```

> test_test.py

```
from test import Connection

sparkConnect = Connection()
```

when I run test.py the connection is made successfully but with test_test.py it gives

raise KeyError(key)

KeyError: 'SPARK_HOME'

Answer (score 1):

`KEY_ERROR` arises if the `SPARK_HOME` is not found or invalid. So it's better to add it to your `bashrc` and check and reload in your code. So add this at the top of your `test.py`

```
import os
import sys
import pyspark
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf, SQLContext

# Create a variable for our root path
SPARK_HOME = os.environ.get('SPARK_HOME',None)
# Add the PySpark/py4j to the Python Path
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(SPARK_HOME, "python", "lib"))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(SPARK_HOME, "python"))

pyspark_submit_args = os.environ.get("PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS", "")
if not "pyspark-shell" in pyspark_submit_args: pyspark_submit_args += " pyspark-shell"
os.environ["PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS"] = pyspark_submit_args
```

Also add this at the end of your ~/.bashrc file

COMMAND: `vim ~/.bashrc` if you are using any Linux based OS

```
# needed for Apache Spark
export SPARK_HOME="/opt/spark"
export IPYTHON="1"
export PYSPARK_PYTHON="/usr/bin/python3"
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON="ipython3"
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook"
export PYTHONPATH="$SPARK_HOME/python/:$PYTHONPATH"
export PYTHONPATH="$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip:$PYTHONPATH"
export PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS="--master local[2] pyspark-shell"
export CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:/opt/spark/lib/spark-assembly-1.6.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar
```

**Note:**

1. In the above bashrc code, I have given my SPARK_HOME value as `/opt/spark` you can give the location where you keep your spark folder(the downloaded one from the website).
2. Also I'm using `python3` you can change it to `python` in the bashrc if you are using python 2.+ versions
3. I was using Ipython, for easy testing during runtime, like load the data once and test your code many times. If you are using plain old text editor, let me know I will update the bashrc accordingly.

Comment: Why is this happening, why can't PyCharm get 'SPARK_HOME' when I'm running from a different file?

Comment: I tested your code in my PC in vim. Your code prints "all done" after runnig both `.py` files separately. So the problem is in your `SPARK_HOME` location. Have you set it in your OS. I assumed you are using Linux OS.

Comment: Yes I'm using ubuntu with PyCharm IDE, but on running test_test.py file it raises key error for 'SPARK_HOME' unlike when I run test.py file. Also I've given path of 'SPARK_HOME' in .bashrc as test.py file runs successfully.

Comment: did you check it separately in a terminal and not in an IDE ?.

Comment: Di you get any results?